# Is Physics Stack Exchange even as active as before?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I always get on physics.se in my free time. I've been doing this for around 2 years now. But I feel like, over the recent weeks, the site has slowed down dramatically. There are fewer people answering questions AND most importantly, most a lot of the questions are duplicates. Is it just me or are we running out of questions?

Comment: Concerning the title question (v2): Well, last month (February 2017) saw in average roughly 110 questions, 120 answers, 90000 visitors & 130000 total page views per day, which are at the record-level for Phys.SE.

Comment: I've had the exact opposite feeling -- there are far more questions I am interested in answering lately, so many so that I cannot keep up with it in my spare time. Perhaps it's just questions in your area of interest that feel less frequent?

Comment: This isn't the first time someone has asked if we're as active as before, nor is it the first time someone has suggested we might be running out of questions. There are natural fluctuations in site activity and we've had lots of duplicates for as long as I've been here. History has shown that there will always be new good questions and that, on average, the site sees more activity over time

Comment: Ahh ok, thx for the confirmations. So glad the site isn't falling

Comment: You can get a more detailed stat since the existence of the site [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/649165/number-of-open-closed-and-deleted-questions-by-month#graph).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Much of the data is public, over at [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), so you can go and do some number-crunching yourself.

Some of the data is available only to mods, and some is available to >25k rep users, and it shows no such decline. Over the period since January 2015, we have

[image]

[image]

[image]

There are some seasonal variations (such as the obvious dips over the Christmas holidays, and some slower traffic over the summer) and a slow but steady growth. Now, of course, this is an incomplete picture, but the effects you mention should be measurable via the data explorer, so if they're there, you can go and do the number-crunching and convince us that indeed there are some worrisome metrics.

(So much, of course, for the measurable stuff. The intangibles are another matter.)

Comment: The ticks on the x-axis seems to be about 4.5 days short of a quarter. Can you make them align (approximately) to year / month boundaries?

Comment: The vertical axes seem to count weekly tallies.

Comment: @PeterMortensen No. The only control we get over those graphs is the date range they're graphed over. Frankly, it's just not interesting enough to delve into more details, I think. And yes, the vertical axis is almost certainly a weekly tally, though the absolute values have so little context they're essentially meaningless as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Love the stats. Thank you for confirming